# jquerymobile: determine device orientation

Tags: jquery-mobile, device-orientation

```
$(window).bind("orientationchange", function(e){
   var ow = (e.orientation=="portrait" ? "縦" : "横");
   alert("端末の向きは "+ow+" です。");
});
```

using the above code, i could determine if the device is in portrait or landscape mode. But my question is, is it possible to determine which side on the landscape (landscape right/ landscape left) is the device tilted, also if the device is upsidedown?

thanks guys for the support.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange', function() {
   alert(window.orientation);
});
```

- 0 = Portrait orientation. This is the default value
- -90 = Landscape orientation with the screen turned clockwise
- 90 = Landscape orientation with the screen turned counterclockwise
- 180 = Portrait orientation with the screen turned upside down

Comment: is this supported by all mobile browsers?

Answer (score 1):

I would take into consideration this post:

http://www.matthewgifford.com/2011/12/22/a-misconception-about-window-orientation/

Comment: thanks man, know what? i tried this myself a couple of days ago with iphone and an android tablet and the android behaves very differently than iOS so when i check the values of the orientation its very different (exact opposite on iphone)... arrrgh!

Comment: Updated link: https://notes.matthewgifford.com/a-misconception-about-window-orientation-7231235a94c2

Answer (score 1):

Most simple answer: Get the orientation (at any time in your js code) via

```
window.orientation
```

When `window.orientation` returns `0` or `180` then you are in **portrait mode**, when returning `90` or `270` then you are in **landscape mode**.